# Angular 5: nebular/ ngx-admin: Component themable styles

Tags: sass, angular5

how can i add different styling (eg. border color) to both the checkboxes in the image below using the [themable style](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/#/docs/components/checkbox#NbCheckboxComponentStyles) of nebular frontend framework.

[image]

here is the html code

`<nb-checkbox>without shortcomings</nb-checkbox>
<nb-checkbox>Defects without without defects</nb-checkbox>`

I am using `.scss`

Answer (score 0):

Using the nebular theme system and producing a different style for the checkboxes is not possible because "checkbox-bg" style is applied globally so whatever background color you give will be applied to all the checkboxes in the application.

What I would recommend is to write a custom class .without-shortcomings and override the style.

```
.without-shortcomings{
//overide style either component level or global
  background-color: #fff;
}


<nb-checkbox class="without-shortcomings">without shortcomings</nb-checkbox>
<nb-checkbox>Defects without without defects</nb-checkbox>
```

Comment: @ThomasT.brhan Thank you removed the code snippet as it was an approach on how to solve the above issue. Not a complete snippet which can solve the problem of this question